# How can I open the word in AutoIt using Java

Tags: java, eclipse, autoit

I am using the below code to open and write in the word. However I am unable to open it.

```
File file = new File("lib", jacobDllVersionToUse);
    System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());

    AutoItX x = new AutoItX();
    x.run("Microsoft Office Word 2007.Application");
    x.winActivate("[CLASS:OpusApp]");
    x.winWait("[CLASS:OpusApp]");
    //x.controlFocus("[CLASS:AcrobatSDIWindow]", "", "AVL_AVView17");
    x.sleep(1000);
    x.send("this is some text");
```

When I am opening the word manually the above code is able to write in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying different way to open the file and my one way worked. Now I am able to open the word using autoit.

Below is the code for the same :

```
    File file = new File("lib", jacobDllVersionToUse);
    System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());
    AutoItX x = new AutoItX();
    x.run("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\WINWORD.EXE");
    x.winActivate("[CLASS:OpusApp]");
    x.winWait("[CLASS:OpusApp]");
    x.sleep(1000);
    x.send("this is some text");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are functions, especially for Word, which could be useful. I don't know if they work for java plug-in but give it a try:

[_Word_Create](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Word_Create.htm)

[_Word_DocOpen](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Word_DocOpen.htm)

[_Word_DocSave](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Word_DocSave.htm)

[_Word_DocSaveAs](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Word_DocSaveAs.htm)

[_Word_DocClose](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Word_DocClose.htm)

[_Word_Quit](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Word_Quit.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions Ike. However I am unable to use all these functions in Java.

Comment: These are AutoIT UDFs. They are purely written in autoit scripting. For the moment there is no java wrapper for these functions.